# Canvas clearRect performance very different when increasing w/h by 1px

Tags: javascript, html, performance, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm seeing a really odd canvas `clearRect` performance issue.

In our game, the current move is rendered with a small white square 7px * 7px.

Once that move is over the square is removed with a `clearRect(x, y, 7, 7)` function.

This performs fine, but leaves a weird white outline behind. Which I believe is sub pixel rounding:

[image]

I can solve this, by issuing a different `clearRect` call, specifically `clearRect(x, y - 1, 8, 8)` this removes the white `residue` which kind of confirms the sub-pixel theory, but for some reason the performance is significantly worse.

This is the initial 7*7 clear: https://www.useloom.com/share/9b6bbd00647a4803ad5d0a8a4ce77d3a

And this is the 8x8 clear:
https://www.useloom.com/share/c36f7b2e81e74d1d9bfd9e16124a7503

Should  I really be seeing this jank with such a small change?

To put things into context, each frame I have a series of `messages` to render (the coloured squares / crosses) these could number 1-2000. I also need to render the current message in a different colour (which is on a different canvas).

So I have a function `renderMessages` responsible for rendering each message each frame.

```
  renderMessages() {    

    this.messages.forEach((data) => {
      this.renderCurrentTask(data)
      this.renderCell(data)
    })

    this.messages = []

    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.renderMessages())
  }
```

The function where I'm drawing and then clearing the canvas is `renderCurrentTask`. As a result when I try to use something simple like a `clearRect(0,0,w,h)` I'm seeing poor perf as I have to call it maybe 2000 per frame.

If it's any help in diagnosing this is my `renderCurrentTask` function where the small `clearRect` change has the negative effect:

```
  renderCurrentTask(data) {

    if(this.lastCoordinates) {

      this.interactiveContext.clearRect(this.lastCoordinates.x,
        this.lastCoordinates.y,
        this.lastCoordinates.wh,
        this.lastCoordinates.wh)
    }

    const coordinate = this.addressToScreenCoordinate(data.address)

    this.interactiveContext.fillStyle = '#ffffff'

    this.interactiveContext.fillRect(
      coordinate.x,
      coordinate.y,
      this.cellSize,
      this.cellSize)

    this.lastCoordinates = {
      x: coordinate.x,
      y: coordinate. y - 1,
      wh: this.cellSize + 2
    }

  }
```

Comment: clear everything once per frame, it will be way easier to manage and should not have too much impact on performances. If you have some layers that are updated less often than others, consider rendrering these on off screen canvases.

Comment: Clearing the entire canvas totally nails the performance, this is what I had before changing to just clearing a small area.
Have a look at this video where I do a `clearRect(0,0,width, height)` if you want to see: https://www.useloom.com/share/e3aceb51ffb1402c85fe0840af26e4dc

Comment: It shouldn't, at least if your canvas area is not a few mega px large. Your performance issues most likely come from something else, but there is no code to chew on to be able to find out what it is. But if you really want to go the small area way, round your x and y values for both drawing and clearing and double check you do use the previous frame's ones for clearing.

Comment: I expanded the q to add some context, basically I have to draw and reclear multiple times per frame. You're right if I remove the `clearRect` and call it once per frame the perf is ok, but I need to run the routine maybe thousands of times per frame

Comment: I can confirm the values are rounded and the x,y,w,h are what I'd expect. I think I may have just reached the limit on what my gfx card can do :(

Comment: Just a random idea for debugging this, but what happens when you replace clearRect with fillRect with background colour?

Comment: I did think about that, but at the moment I have two canvas' the one on top is the one which needs clearing. I need to see the contents below so need it to go transparent rather than colour filled.

Comment: Make sure that the clear is at pixel boundaries..You may need to change the layout a little. `ctx.clearRect(x | 0, y | 0, 7, 7)` will clear without leaving any aliased edges. The `| 0` is the same a `Math.floor`

Comment: I don't see why you need to render+clear 2000 times per frame. Rebuild your rendering system so that every frame (60 times per second) you draw only what needs to be drawn, in a single throw. Looking at your screenshots, we can tell by the growing artifacts that you are drawing multilple times at the same positions, this is the sign of a bad design. Draw the black background + grid once on a offscreen canvas, at every new message, update your js object holding these. At every new frame, filter overlapping messages out, drawImage the bg canvas, draw only the shapes that should be visible.

Comment: I tend to agree that your life would be a lot easier if you can just clear the entire canvas and reduce all these drawing calls per frame, but my hunches for your immediate problem is either something going on with sub-pixel sampling if the API accepts floating-point inputs, for which it should help to make sure everything is rounded to integer coordinates. The other could be increased cache misses and evictions. If that's the case, it might help considerably if you can draw/clear all your tiles in a cache-friendly way (left-to-right, top-to-bottom, not in a random pattern).

Comment: Drawing/clearing in this type of sequential order should help no matter what you do. If it's too difficult to do perfectly, see if you can at least draw in a top-to-bottom fashion. Don't start drawing/clearing tiles in row 17 only to go to row 5, then row 2, then row 17 again, then row 2 again, e.g., all in a single frame. Process the rows from top to bottom to reduce the chance of scanline data from the image being evicted only to be reloaded again in the same frame. Do everything you need to with row 0, then do everything you need to with row 1, and so forth, not zig-zagging back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

If your canvas game has performance issue even after trying different methods to optimize it, you could try using webgl renderer. I suggest using a library for rendering 2d using webgl, for example [Pixi.js](http://www.pixijs.com/). This solution could require a lot of rewriting your current code tho.

Comment: Interesting idea, due to how low level and simple my redraws are though and that I have a need to draw many times per frame. I'm keener to find a way to optimise the process rather than write a new one